# request.getHeader('referer') does not work with POST Method

Tags: grails, post, http-status-code-405

I search a proper way to go back to the last visited page : 
i find this solution :

```
request.getHeader('referer')
```

I try to save it in input hidden as following :

```
<input type="hidden" value="${request.getHeader('referer') }" name="lastVisited" />
```

However , when i try to display it by an action , i get : `405 error`
This action is defined in allowedMethods map as a static field of conttroller :

```
static allowedMethods = [show: "POST"]
```

**UPDATE :**

```
class InsatController{
   static allowedMethods=[save:'POST',show:'POST']

    def show(){
     [insatien:Insat.get(params?.id as Long)]   
   }



}
```

Now in /insat/show.gsp ,i have

```
 <input type="hidden" value="${request.getHeader('referer') }" name="lastVisited" />
```

Comment: please show your gsp/controller

Comment: So, you got 405 on show() action, right? how do you access this action? are you sure that it's POST request?

Comment: A redirect from one site to another will be a GET action.